# C# Class library collections ObservableCollection<T> vs Collection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I'm creating a class library that could be used in a number of situations ASP.NET, Console Apps, other class libraries and XAML targets like Silverlight or WPF.

Initially I decided to expose collections as IList.  But then when writing samples using  XAML I found that if I want to make it easy to bind to these collections I need to use ObservableCollection.

What are my options?

I could make the library expose ObservableCollection and force that upon users who have nothing to do with XAML.  Is that a bad thing?

I could make my class generic allowing the caller to specify the collection type they want as long as it implements ICollection perhaps with default to Collection

I could make a set of classes one that uses ObservableCollection and one that does not say Foo and ObservableFoo.

I could implement INotifyCollectionChanged in my class but that seems silly when ObservableCollection does it for me.

Obviously I'm trying to keep the code clean and simple, but supporting data binding seems important.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Tried creating a Portable Class Library project using both alternatives.

In class Foo I have

```
    private readonly Collection<string> strings = new Collection<string>();

    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> Strings
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(this.strings);
        }
    }
```

In class ObservableFoo I have

```
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> Strings
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(this.strings);
        }
    }
```

The very simple unit test code is

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var foo = new ObservableFoo(); // or new Foo()

        Assert.AreNotEqual(0, foo.Id);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0, foo.Strings.Count);
    }
```

The only downside is that when I used ReadOnlyObservableCollection the test project got this compile error

> The type
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'

So in this case, using ReadOnlyObservableCollection would force users to add a reference to System.Windows which is a downside.

**Edit: I came up with a solution that I posted on my blog - see [How to make a library portable and data binding friendly at the same time?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2012/07/22/how-to-make-a-library-portable-and-data-binding-friendly-at-the-same-time.aspx)**

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provided a concise code sample.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends. If you are writing a pure model library, it makes no sense to expose WPF-specific interfaces; this would force the users link against WPF libraries even if they don't need to. Even if it were not, it exposes something that the users are not going to need, which is not a good design IMHO.

If your library is not limited to model usage, I would split it into several parts: core needed for all usage scenarios, WPF-dependent part with WPF-specific interfaces, maybe ASP-specific part with ASP-specific features and so on. The users will pick the parts they need and use them.

---

Edit: as @Julien's comment states, `ObservableCollection<T>` is now as part of core, so including it won't make the users depend from the WPF-specific libraries. Nevertheless, the idea stays the same. For WPF usage, you often need to offer/work with specific features (`ObservableCollection`, `INotifyPropertyChanged`/`DependencyObject`, dependency properties, notifications in UI thread only and so on). This means that they belong to a separate, WPF-specific part of the project.

So you can make the library consist of several parts: Library.Core.dll containing functions needed for generic/model development, Library.WPF.dll dealing with WPF-specific stuff and using Library.Core.dll, maybe Library.Console.dll and Library.ASP.dll as well. Users of WPF will use Library.Core.dll and Library.WPF.dll, console programs might need Library.Core.dll and Library.Console.dll and so on.

Comment: I agree with your post but would like to precise that since .NET 4, `ObservableCollection` and other similar types have been moved from WindowsBase.dll to System.dll, so they're not really WPF specific anymore.

Comment: So then... if ObservableCollection is not WPF specific and nobody is adding event handlers to the INotifyCollectionChanged interface perhaps the idea of using this type as the collection type is not so bad after all?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the low-level components of your library should offer interfaces that make sense for those components, at that particular level of abstraction, without regard to how the various consumers of your API might need to adapt them for their own uses.

For example, if a composite WPF application would use your components, it would be wholly appropriate for those applications to encapsulate your components into a Model or View Model that adapts the `IList<T>` (or better still, `IEnumerable<T>`) offered by your components into an `ObservableCollection<T>` suitable for binding to a view.

A console application might not need such overhead, and could happily use the `IEnumerable<T>`.

As an aside, be careful even when exposing collections as `IList<T>`. This allows consumers of your library to add to and remove items from the list, for example, which might not be in the spirit of the interface.

Comment: I thought of that but wrapping an IEnumerable<string> with an ObservableCollection requires the user to copy each string into the ObservableCollection which seems sub-optimal.

Comment: That's true, but if callers require that the collection be observable by a view (implying that the collection could change over time), they are going to be calling (polling) your component periodically to get the latest list, and updating their collection accordingly, so there is going to be overhead in any case. Of course, if it make sense for your component to notify consumers about changes to the collection, then it makes perfect sense to offer ObservableCollection to callers.

Comment: @RonJacobs and having all the consumers that do not need the observable abilities pay the cost of having those is not sub-optimal?

Comment: @RuneFS After browsing the source for ObservableCollection<T> if nobody subscribes to the notifications I suspect the additional overhead is probably quite small unless the number of items collection is very large.  In my case, the number of items in the collection is probably almost always less than 100.

Comment: @RonJacobs and the same is true for the cost you are trying to avoid for some (creating a new collection with less than 100 items)